# Difference between an integer column and integer values in a list column

Tags: r, data.table

Suppose there is a data.table as under:

```
exp <- structure(list(
  id = c("a", "b"),
  num1 = c(1L, 5L),
  num2 = list(c(2L, 5L, 8L),
              c(6L, 10L, 13L, 19L))),
  .Names = c("id", "num1", "num2"),
  row.names = c(NA, -2L),
  class = c("data.table", "data.frame"))
```

See the data.table:

```
exp
   id num1        num2
1:  a    1       2,5,8
2:  b    5  6,10,13,19
```

Also see the structure:

```
str(exp)
Classes ‘data.table’ and 'data.frame':  2 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ id  : chr  "a" "b"
 $ num1: int  1 5
 $ num2:List of 2
  ..$ : int  2 5 8
  ..$ : int  6 10 13 19
```

My problem is how to create an additional column (say, diff) which will show the difference between num1 (integer) and num2 (list containing integers) columns. For the **first row** it should show **1, 4, 7** and for **second row** it should show **1, 5, 8, 14**.

The following code obviously does not work:

```
exp[, `:=`(diff = num1 - num2)]
```

Neither does

```
exp[, `:=`(diff = num1 - unlist(num2))]
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Why not unnest the list? `exp[ , .(num2 = unlist(num2)), by = .(id, num1)][ , .(num2 - num1)]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question simplifies to a question about subtracting lists from a vector:

```
num1 <- c(1L, 5L)
num2 <- list(c(2L, 5L, 8L),
             c(6L, 10L, 13L, 19L))
# Method A: these are both defined
num1[[1]] - num2[[1]]
num1[[2]] - num2[[2]]
# Method B: this is not:
num1 - num2
# This is how you programatically do Method A:
mapply(`-`, num1, num2)
```

Just put the mapply call in your data table subset expression.

Comment: Thanks. Till now `lapply` and `sapply` served all my purposes. Now I get a chance to use and hence learn `mapply`.

Comment: You're welcome!  `mapply` is a great one because it allows you to pass vectors as ALL the arguments to FUN, instead of just one. And if you want your mind blown, start fiddling with `Vectorize`, which is a wrapper to mapply.

Answer (score 3):

This can be done using `Map`:

```
exp[, diff := Map("-", num2, num1)]
exp
#   id num1        num2        diff
#1:  a    1       2,5,8       1,4,7
#2:  b    5  6,10,13,19  1, 5, 8,14
```

The num1-values are recycled to the length of the num2 list-element and then subtracted. `Map` always returns a list-result.

Comment: Thanks. Just noticed that `Map` is a simple wrapper to `mapply` which does not attempt to simplify the result.